# Multiple action on string in ruby in one go

Tags: ruby

Here is a string a content is "hi all I'm new here(seriously)"
How can I return a "hi+all+I'm+new+here" using ruby code?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Also the last result already has added leading space on it and that makes it confusing: `(space)hi+all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply chain the `.gsub()` commands?

```
x.gsub(/\(.*?\)/, '').gsub(/\s+/,'+')
```

Also, you can update your first `gsub` to delete any whitespace preceding the brackets aswell.

```
x.gsub(/\s+\(.*?\)/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use a single `gsub` operation, you can pass a [hash as the replacement parameter](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/10/03/using-rubys-gsub-with-a-hash/):

```
x.gsub(/( *\(.*?\)| )/, ' ' => '+', default: '')
# => "hi+all"
```

What this does is captures either something in brackets (including the leading spaces) or spaces. If the capture is a space - it is replaced by `'+'`, otherwise, it replaces to empty string `''`